# ::before, ::after content alignment wrong on windows

Tags: css

I have font icons i'm using for that before, after selector. But it's alignment seems wrong on windows.

mac view

[image]

Windows

[image]

selector doesn't have any line-height, padding something like that. just has color and font-size properties.

css code

```
content: 'X';
position: absolute;
left: 335px;
bottom: 0;
color: #ee6969;
```

I'm using latest version Chrome.

Comment: Are you writing CSS from scratch? Did you reset the default values?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: I have reset.css for reset.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or something so we can test it outselves?

Comment: also specify what browser you used.

Comment: post your full code this is not enough

Comment: Did you try add z-index value to :after element?